# Box diagram with arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows

Do you have any ideas for drawing a diagram like this? (box, arrow, etc.)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are plenty of similar examples on this site. Please first consult these. If you got stuck and have a concrete problem, feel free to edit your question and provide a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...  Hope this may helps you... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603650/writing-flowchart

Comment: As of my opinion, please do not downvote for beginner's questions, please

Comment: @GowriSaro Done! please do not downvote for beginner's questions

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Any news? Is any of received answers acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Filling up the data is always difficult - do try and give the basics in your question as a MWE(minimum working example) as described on TEX website

I have laid out the basic structure along with a few arrows which seem complicated and the syntax is fairly easy to understand - notwithstanding queries are welcome in case of any difficulties

I think you should be able to proceed here onwards

All the best

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{
        basic/.style={
            draw,
            rectangle,
            minimum width=9em,
            text centered
        },
        arrsty/.style={
            draw=black,
            -latex
        }
    }
    
    % use sans serif font by default
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
        \tikzset{every node}=[font=\tiny]
        
            [every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
            \node[basic] (frm) {Flood Risk Map};
            \node[basic, above=of frm] (woa) {Weighted Overlay Analysis};
            \node[basic, above=of woa] (rec) {Reclassify};
            \node[basic, above=of rec] (ed) {Euclidean Distance};
            \node[basic, above=of ed] (stf) {Stream to Feature};            
            \node[basic, above=of stf] (fa) {Flow accumulation};
            \node[basic, above=of fa] (fd) {Flow Direction};    
            \node[basic, above=of fd] (dem) {DEM};
            
            \node[basic, left=of dem] (slope) {Slope};

            \node[basic, right=of dem] (lc) {Land Cover};                               
            \node[basic, right=of lc] (rain) {Rainfall};

            \coordinate[below=of $(lc)!0.5!(rain)$] (aux);
            
            \draw[arrsty]   (lc)    |-  (aux)   |- (rec);
            \draw[arrsty]   (rain)  |-  (aux)   |- (rec);
            
            \coordinate[below=2em of $(dem)!0.5!(slope)$] (aux1);
            
            \draw[arrsty]   (dem)   |-  (aux1)  -| (slope);
            
            \draw[arrsty]   (fd)    --  (fa);
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using @js bibra answer (+1) as starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Stealth,
node distance = 5mm and 6mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   box/.style = {draw, semithick, font=\small\sffamily,
                 minimum height=4ex, text width=24mm, align=flush center},
every edge/.append style = {draw, ->}   
                        ]
% nodes in the main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={box, on chain=A}]
\node   {Flow Direction};               % A-1
\node   {Flow accumulation};
\node   {Stream to Feature};
\node   {Euclidean Distance};
\node   {Reclassify};
\node   {Weighted Overlay Analysis};
\node   {Flood Risk Map};               % A-7
    \end{scope}
% arrows in main branch
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,3,4,...,6}
\draw   (A-\i) edge (A-\j);
% nodes in the left branch
\node (fill)    [box, left=of A-1]  {Fill};
\node (rstr)    [box, left=of A-2]  {Raster calculator};
\node (strm)    [box, left=of A-3]  {Raster calculator};
% arrows in left branch
\draw   (A-2)  edge (rstr)
        (rstr) edge (strm)
        (strm) edge (A-3);
% nodes in the top row
\node (dem)     [box, above=of fill] {DEM};
\node (slp)     [box, left=of dem]   {Slope};
%
\node (lc)      [box, right=of dem -| A-1.east]  {Land Cover};
\node (rain)    [box, right=of lc]               {Rainfall};
% arrows on top
\draw   (dem) edge (slp)  
        (dem) edge coordinate (aux) (fill) ;
\draw[->] (aux) -| ([xshift=-1em] fill.west) |- (A-5);
\coordinate[below=of $(lc)!0.5!(rain)$] (aux);
\draw[->]   (lc)   |- (aux);
\draw[->]   (rain) |- (aux);
\draw[->]   (aux)  |- (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]